# OutputStream.write only writing part of a String in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java-based IRC client as a way to learn both Java and more about writing networked applications.

The client I've designed mostly works, except when I post a message. The message goes through alright, but only up to the first space. I've tried everything: I've dumped my text into a StringArray, into a byte array, in a loop. But each time, only the first word of the intended message gets posted.

Here's the part of the code that I believe is relevant, although I'm happy to post the entire code if necessary (it's only a few hundred lines, and I can cut out the unimportant parts):

```
public void send(String msg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if ( ! msg.startsWith("/")) {
        msg = ("PRIVMSG " + chan + " " + msg);
        // DEBUG confirm that msg == command+chan+userText
        System.out.println(msg); 
        } else if ( msg.toUpperCase().startsWith("/JOIN ")) {
        // System.out.println("\nJoin mode");
            chan = msg.substring(6);
            msg = (msg.toUpperCase().substring(1) + "\r\n");
        } else { // some other command
            msg = (msg.toUpperCase().substring(1) + "\r\n");
        }

        System.out.println(msg);
        ostream.print(msg + " \r\n"); // doesn't work
        ostream.flush();
        }
    }
```

I have also tried this sort of thing:

```
CRS = msg.split("\\s+");
CharSequence chars = msg;
ostream.printf( "%s,\r\n", msg); // doesn't work
ostream.print( String.join(" ", CRS) + "\r\n" ); // nope
```

And this:

```
ostream.append(chars);
ostream.append("\r\n"); // nope
```

I've also tried all of the above with byte arrays.

This sort of thing, however, does work:

```
// this, however, works as expected
void pong(String ping) {
    String msg = "PONG " + ping;
    byte[] bs  = null;
    bs = (msg.substring(1) + "\r\n").getBytes();
    try {
        ostream.write(bs);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've also tried changing my `OutputStream` object (the connection to the IRC server) to a PrintStream. Same results.

What about OutputStream am I not comprehending?

Comment: PircBot is pretty nasty. There are cleaner versions of it (as well as other frameworks that abide by the RFC), so I recommend checking them out. Either way, **have you tried flushing the stream?** Call `ostream.flush()` to flush the stream.

Comment: How are you *reading* this data? It is infinitely more likely that you have a bug in your reading code than that `OutputStream.write()` has mysteriously developed a bug after 22 years.

Comment: **msg** probably doesn't contain what you think it does. What is filling the **msg** variable?

Comment: @DevilsHnd `msg` is populated by a `TextField.getText()` lambda. I [think I] can confirm that `msg` contains what I think it contains with a `System.out.println(msg);` just before writing to ostream.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I tried calling ostream.flush() just before writing to it, and there is no change in behavior.

Comment: @EJP I'm reading the output from the server as a BufferedReader stream. When testing, I log in as a separate user on the same server with a known-good IRC client (Konversation, for instance, so I can confirm that I'm reading the data accurately (messages that appear in my usual desktop IRC client also appear in my personal Java client). Messages sent from my client are definitely truncated on the server.

Comment: No. Don't tell us what you think your code does. If it really did that, you wouldn't be posting here. Post the code in your question.

Comment: Flush *after* writing, not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IRC protocol requires you to escape messages that contain spaces with a preceding colon (":"). I think your code actually works, you've just not implemented the IRC protocol correctly.

Try making your `PRIVMSG` command:

```
msg = ("PRIVMSG " + chan + " :" + msg);
```

Only the first word is appearing because the IRC server ignores the trailing content after the first space. A valid message should look like:

```
PRIVMSG #target :Hello, world
```